# Priority and split and adding a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Guys i have this excel data here as

[image]

and i want to convert it to something like this

[image]

FACTORYLINECODE is just VBR

SMP NO = STD(priority 1)

USAP NO = USA(priority 2)

OE NO. = OEM(priority 3)

ignore PG order

i achived this through power query. im new to pandas and python and would love to learn
how would i achive this with pandas. i thougt of using split at OE NO. but stuck there

Comment: What you need is a `melt`, then cleaning of the data. If you need help you must provide reproducible data and code and a fair attempt to solve it by yourself.

Comment: `OE NO.` contains '\n' or space?

Comment: its \n newline at OE NO.

Comment: @mozway. i spilt the OEM NO. through str.split ("\n") but after that i think i need to pivot it but i dont know exactly how thats why i posted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important part of your problem is to clean your data before `melt`:

```
d = {'V-Bright NO.': 'Factory Part', 'SMP NO.': 'STD', 'USAP NO.': 'USA', 'OE NO.': 'OEM'}
p = {'STD': 1, 'USA': 2, 'OEM': 3}
c = ['FactoryLinecode', 'Factory Part', 'Linecode', 'InterchangePart', 'Priority']

out = (df.rename(columns=d)[d.values()]
         .melt(['Factory Part'], var_name='Linecode', value_name='InterchangePart')
         .assign(InterchangePart=lambda x: x['InterchangePart'].str.split('\n'),
                 Priority=lambda x: x['Linecode'].map(p), FactoryLinecode='VBR')
         .explode('InterchangePart')[c])
```

Output:

| FactoryLinecode | Factory Part | Linecode | InterchangePart | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VBR | VB-9400 | STD | UF499 | 1 |
| VBR | VB-9400 | USA | REPK504603 | 2 |
| VBR | VB-9400 | OEM | 2730126640 | 3 |
| VBR | VB-9400 | OEM | 0986221077 | 3 |

Comment: it's really different (except for plain text)? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73170960/15239951

Comment: I could copy the data ;) but yes much too often the pandas question are lacking an attempt